# ANTD: how to change the text inside the pagination select box

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, antd

how can I change the text inside the ant design pagination select?
there's no solution in the documents,

I need to change the word "**page**" to something else:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching almost everywhere, I came to this conclusion that there's not a normal way to change the default words.

For changing the **language** there's the [locale](https://ant.design/docs/react/i18n) option, and in the files defined for **locale** we can change the default words, which is an unusual thing to do but not impossible!

Answer (score 7):

I try this solution and it works.

```
<Pagination
    defaultCurrent={1}
    total={50}
    locale={{ items_per_page: "/ หน้า"}}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pagination={{
      locale: {
        items_per_page: intl.formatMessage({ id: "common-table-per-page" }),
      },
    }}
```