# Antd Pagination change "page" text

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I'm using antd pagination and i need to change the "page" text to something else. There is a way to change language but i don't want to change language i want to change "page" to "product". I couldn't find anything in [docs](https://ant.design/components/pagination/#header) [image]

You can find the codesandbox link [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/mpem84) to try it. I took it from the docs

Comment: You can check this answer on this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65588379/antd-how-to-change-the-text-inside-the-pagination-select-box

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can simply use:

```
<Pagination locale={{ items_per_page: '' }} />
```

Comment: It works thx a lot. May i ask another question, is there any way to take that selectbox to left side of the pagination?

Comment: i think we can achieve that by CSS.

Comment: Yes found it. If anyone need it, .ant-pagination-options {float: left;} it achieves what you wanted. Thx a lot again!